# Error in spfeml(formula = formula, data = data, index = index, listw = listw, : Non conformable arguments using in R

Tags: r

i have some trouble with my R code for spatial panel, because it's panel model so my data is 175 from few periods  2015-2019 with 35 unique region.

Here's the data:

```
IPM_Jateng <- IPM_Jawa_Tengah
head(IPM_Jateng)
 NAMA_KAB     Tahun   IPM   AHH   HLS  RRLS    PP    PDRB    KP   BFK
  <chr>        <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 CILACAP      2019   70.0  73.5  12.5  6.93 10639 100446.  813.  2256
2 BANYUMAS     2019   72.0  73.6  12.8  7.42 11703  39779. 1268.  2626
3 PURBALINGGA  2019   69.0  73.0  12.0  7.14 10131  17388. 1378.  1266
4 BANJARNEGARA 2019   67.3  74.0  11.4  6.5   9547  15247.  902.  1631
5 KEBUMEN      2019   69.6  73.2  13.0  7.53  9066  19825.  989.  2175
6 PURWOREJO    2019   72.5  74.5  13.5  7.91 10342  13361.  658.  1686
```

Cause the region just have 35 so i merge it with this code

```
datamerge <- merge(jateng,IPM_Jateng,id='NAMA_KAB')
head(datamerge)
Simple feature collection with 6 features and 13 fields
geometry type:  MULTIPOLYGON
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 108.8903 ymin: -7.662905 xmax: 109.9138 ymax: -7.170602
epsg (SRID):    NA
proj4string:    NA
NAMA_KAB KODE_KAB KODE_PROP   NAMA_PROP Tahun   IPM   AHH   HLS RRLS    PP
1 BANJARNEGARA     3304        33 JAWA TENGAH  2019 67.34 74.01 11.45 6.50  9547
2 BANJARNEGARA     3304        33 JAWA TENGAH  2016 65.52 73.69 11.40 6.26  8400     
3 BANJARNEGARA     3304        33 JAWA TENGAH  2017 65.86 73.79 11.41 6.27  8630
4 BANJARNEGARA     3304        33 JAWA TENGAH  2018 66.54 73.91 11.42 6.28  9160
5 BANJARNEGARA     3304        33 JAWA TENGAH  2015 64.73 73.59 11.39 6.17  7930
6     BANYUMAS     3302        33 JAWA TENGAH  2018 71.30 73.45 12.64 7.41 11240

      PDRB      KP  BFK                       geometry
1 15246.87  901.79 1631 MULTIPOLYGON (((109.7433 -7...
2 12932.88  848.25 1837 MULTIPOLYGON (((109.7433 -7...
3 13663.27  853.00 1822 MULTIPOLYGON (((109.7433 -7...
4 14438.15  858.00 1627 MULTIPOLYGON (((109.7433 -7...
5 12166.05  843.00 1830 MULTIPOLYGON (((109.7433 -7...
6 37414.50 1265.00 2687 MULTIPOLYGON (((109.1493 -7...

#weight matrix
list.queen<-poly2nb(datamerge, queen=TRUE)
W<-nb2listw(list.queen, style="W", zero.policy=TRUE)
W
Characteristics of weights list object:
Neighbour list object:
Number of regions: 175
Number of nonzero links: 4400 
Percentage nonzero weights: 14.36735 
Average number of links: 25.14286 

Weights style: W 
Weights constants summary:
    n    nn  S0       S1       S2
W 175 30625 175 15.38857 721.2938

#SEM
coba3<-spml(IPM~AHH+HLS+RRLS+PP+PDRB+BFK,data=datamerge,listw=W,model="within",lag=FALSE)
Error in spfeml(formula = formula, data = data, index = index, listw = listw,  : Non conformable arguments
```

i do anything to fix it but i cant resolve it, somebody can help me please to my project?
btw my coordinates cant read from `datamerge` , you can see below

```
plot(W,coordinates(datamerge),col='red',add=TRUE)
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable): unable to find an inherited method for function ‘coordinates’ for signature ‘"sf"’`
```

i have did `as.data.frame` too but the error became `Error in .local(obj, ...) : 
  cannot derive coordinates from non-numeric matrix`

Is the error from the unreadable coordinates so my model error too?

Here's the data link:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_HNxotPc-XGF62KJldBpz2hBZfNc7QYA

Comment: Please provide some data so that we can help you.

Comment: Welcome to SO. As @Tayfi mentioned please include a minimal dataset in the form of an object for example if a data frame as df <- data.frame(…) where … is your variables and values or use dput(head(df)) to make make your question reproducible. Check out [mre] and [ask] for helpful guidance.

Comment: @Taufi hallo taufi, i have edited the codes and provide the data, thank you taufi for your help

Comment: @Peter hai peter, i have edited and provide the data, or i must upload my data too?